# Logical Methods to Protect Against Ransomware

Tags: ransomware, ntfs

I hate antivirus programs. They hinder more than help. I have some ideas but I have doubts about their practicality...

- Can ransomware infect a FAT32 drive? (As I think they usually benefit from the NTFS encryption feature, FAT32 doesn't have this, but I was in doubt if they usually encrypt using the file system feature, or simply use their own algorithm)
- Ransomware spreads over the network in what way? Can computers connected to the same router but with different domain names be infected?
- Are there any *physical* devices that can stop ransomware?

Comment: Transparent encryption typically will not help against ransomware since the malware is typically running under the user's account, and therefore has access to the encrypted data.

Comment: These are 3 very different questions in one post. We usually keep to just one question per post unless they are closely related. You've got a file systems question, a propagation question, and a remediation question. Your first question is ***trivial*** to answer since a 5 second look up will show you that Linux and MacOS and other file systems get ransomware. And since there are thousands of different kinds of ransomware, how they propagate will be different for different strains.

Answer (score 3):

> Can Ransomware infect a fat32 drive?

Yes

> I think they usually benefit from the ntfs encryption feature, ...

No, ransomware usually comes with their own encryption.

> Ransomware spreads over the network in what way

It depends. It can be through normally mounted network file systems or it can also use security issues like EternalBlue - like with the infamous [WannaCry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WannaCry_ransomware_attack).

Comment: Some ransomware leverages OS encryption

Comment: @schroeder: I did not know that. Fixed it to "usually" - is this correct?

Comment: I'm unsure about the ratio of local to external encryption, and I can't get a sense of that mix after a couple of minutes. So, let's say that most come with their own encryption functions.